# Angular js push changing values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building an application that allows the user to add food items to a basket based on their size (individual, medium large) which are different prices. The problem I am facing is that when I add more than one (using ng-click), the prices for all items in the array are also changing. I can't get my head around it!

When a user selects a product (pizza for example) the variable `selectedProduct` is changed to the selected product.

This is my code to add to the basket:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(key, size, price) {


        //Add selected size and price

        //Add 'extra' for selected price and size
        $scope.selectedProduct.extra = {};
        $scope.selectedProduct.extra = {
            //price is a float
            price: price,
            //$scope.productSizes is a single array that
            //changes int values to sizes (1 => individual, 2 => medium ...)
            size: $scope.productSizes[size],
            //size is the int value of the size
            sizeInt: size
        };

        $scope.cart.push($scope.selectedProduct);
};
```

When I add an item (size = 1) to the array via push I get this in the extra key within the console

```
0 Object
    extra: Object
      price: "1.99"
      size: "Individual"
      sizeInt: 1
```

When I add a second item (size = 3) my array changes both the first and second item in the array

```
0: Object
    extra: Object
      price: "6.5"
      size: "Large"
      sizeInt: 3
1: Object
    extra: Object
      price: "6.5"
      size: "Large"
      sizeInt: 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is happening because you are pushing reference to the `$scope.selectedProduct` into array.

Short example of references:

```js
var a = {'key': 'foo'};
var b = a;
b['key'] = 'bar';
console.log(a['key']);   // initially it was 'foo'
```

I recommend you to create a new object on `addToCart` and push it into array:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(key, size, price) {
    $scope.cart.push({
        extra: {
            price: price,
            size: $scope.productSizes[size],
            sizeInt: size
        }
    });
};
```

Or you can copy `$scope.selectedProduct` on `addToCart` with [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
$scope.addToCart = function(key, size, price) {
    var product = angular.copy($scope.selectedProduct);
    product.extra = {
        price: price,
        size: $scope.productSizes[size],
        sizeInt: size
    };
    $scope.cart.push(product);
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I couldn't figure that out! You fixed my problem :)

Comment: @JakeBown glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're unnecessarily binding `selectedProduct` to `$scope`.

You continuously update and push `$scope.selectedProduct` to the array; and see this result because you are passing the same reference over and over.

Try this:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(key, size, price) {


        //Add selected size and price

        //Add 'extra' for selected price and size
        var selectedProduct = {}; // new reference each time function is called
        selectedProduct.extra = {
            //price is a float
            price: price,
            //$scope.productSizes is a single array that
            //changes int values to sizes (1 => individual, 2 => medium ...)
            size: $scope.productSizes[size],
            //size is the int value of the size
            sizeInt: size
        };

        $scope.cart.push(selectedProduct);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addCart function you should redeclare selectedProduct this way: `$scope.selectedProduct = {}` .
The reason - objects in javascript assigned by reference, and you have the same object in all array elements. So you are updating each one by reference when you changing extra.